# python .txt file is identifying one letter at a time instead of a word in a .txt

Tags: python

first i wold like to say im a very basic programmer so if you can please try not to be complicated however anything is helpful.

I have a .txt file to define a keyword list eg:

```
pig,dog,cat
```

My real list is much bigger but has the same format.

I want the user to input something and if the program detects one of the words which the user imputed and what the .txt file has it common it will give a response. If it doesn't find one of the words if gives a different response.

```
start_question = str(input("keywords are pig , cat , dog "))


with open('D:\Program Files (x86)\Python Programming\python.txt'):
   if any(word in start_question for word in ('D:\Program Files (x86)\PythonProgramming\python.txt')):
   print ("yes")


else:
    print ("no")
```

Now the file successfully opens but instead of finding words in comomon it finds letters in common. So if i input 'p' it will still say 'yes' however i want it to say no.

Thankyou.

Comment: `any(word in start_question for word in ('D:\Program Files (x86)\PythonProgramming\python.txt'))` That does not do what you think it does. You're checking if any of the letters in the literal string `'D:\Program Files (x86)\PythonProgramming\python.txt'` are in `start_question`. I think you need to reread the docs on how to use `with`.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking through the string of the file path, not the contents.

To loop through the file, you'd want to do something like this:

```
with open('D:\Program Files (x86)\Python Programming\python.txt') as fl:
  if any(word in start_question for word in fl):
      print("yes")
  else:
      print("no")
```

But there is another problem, too. If your file is:

```
cat,dog,pig
```

And your input is `cat`, then you'll always get `no`.

Why?

Because you're looking for contents of lines in a file. This means you're seeing

```
if any('cat,dog,pig' in 'cat')
```

That doesn't work.

You'll need to format your file:

```
cat
dog
pig
```

Comment: hello, i now cant find a way to give a yes response.I have reformatted my .txt and still nothing. Also when you edited my program did you just give my file a variable name. As you added a F1 at the end of my code after a as.

Comment: @Callum Look again. `with open(<str>) as fl:` assigns the file pointer to fl.